# How to check if a user disconnect from mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is my table

```
------------------------------------------
| id | room_name | room_status | editing |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1     |     0       |    0    |
| 2  |     2     |     1       |    0    |
------------------------------------------
```

I have Form A and Form B

Form A contain many Button(room), it will update editing column from 0 to 1 and open Form B when Button(room) clicked

Form B contain a Button, it will update editing column from 1 to 0 when the button clicked

*To leave Form B must click the button

*User is not allow to click the Button(room) if editing is equal to 1

If user click on Button(room), and use Task Manager to force exit then the room will locked until I manual change from database

Can mysql detect who is disconnect and change editing to 0 by itself? or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: This sounds a bit like you want a given database record to serve as a mutex or semaphore.  In this case, you should look into row locking with MySQL.

Comment: have any time limit for exit the room??

Comment: @PankajSharma No time limit

Comment: Set value back to `0` when another or same user will click same room again after for example 5 minutes. If itu even can show that room was under "processing" last 10 minutes, so user can click it again and release "lock". Insted `0` use `DateTime` - if `NULL` - can be edited, if `NOT NULL` - editing starts at ...